# Fixing decompiled program errors in C#

Tags: c#, decompiling

When I try to build the program in Visual Studio, I get error CS1908 on line 17 (public SpellScore(string Attempt, string[] Target,...) When I add quotes around the 0, I get the same error. I've also tried null. Any ideas on how the compiler messed it up/what the correct version should be?

```
public class SpellScore
{
    private double MinimumPercent;
    private string mvarAttempt;
    private long mvarAttrib;
    private bool mvarIsCorrect;
    private double mvarResult;
    private SpellingLevels mvarSpellingLevel;
    private string mvarTarget;

    public SpellScore(string Attempt, string[] Target, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(0)] SpellingLevels Level)
    {
        this.mvarIsCorrect = false;
        int upperBound = Target.GetUpperBound(0);
         for (int i = Target.GetLowerBound(0); i <= upperBound; i++)
        {
            if (this.Correct(Attempt, Target[i], Level))
            {
                this.mvarIsCorrect = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The decompiler has shown you the compiler-generated attributes that are included when a method has an optional parameter. For the code to compile as-is, you'd need to make sure you referenced the assembly where those attributes are declared, and include a `using` directive to bring their namespace into scope.

But really, you should edit the decompiled code so it looks like normal C# code, like this:

```
public SpellScore(string Attempt,
    string[] Target, SpellingLevels Level = (SpellingLevels)0)
```

Based on the code you've shown, `SpellingLevels` appears to be an `enum` type. Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know though.

Even better, assuming it is an `enum` type, find out what the `0` value of `SpellingLevels` is, and use the named value instead of `(SpellingLevels)0`.